# How to open/call .bat file with visual basic

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

I'm pretty new at Visaul basic coding, and i would like call/open .Bat file to cmd and send some tokens/variables to it

I already have .Bat file that call this another bat file and code what is there is:
start /min _bin\download.bat "%url%" %convert% %rotate%

But how to do same at Visual basic?

Thanks :)

Comment: I did some searching, and already tested this, but with it i cannot pass those variables to cmd

Comment: You most certainly can. Did you bother to read the documentation for the `Process` class? That post shows you **exactly** how to get started. It's OK to ask for help, but please show at least a small amount of initiative to find a solution, especially when someone puts it right in your hands.

Answer (score -1):

here are some tips & links that may prove helpful.

First, tips when searching previously answered questions:

1. Sometimes the answer accepted in someone else's post isn't your answer (you may be asking a similar, but not exact question)
2. Sometimes your answer can be found in an open question (one without an accepted answer yet)
3. If you're like me, sometimes the more you discover in other questions, the more you realize you don't know yet. But - at least now you know what you don't know... that either means you need to do a google search to fill in the blanks, or post a question admitting you're a newbie (like you did) and make sure to indicate if you have done some legwork on your own and how/where you were stopped.  That gives a bit of context for viewers.

Here are some links that I think might help.  Specifically, help you understand the parameters that can be, but are not required to be passed when calling a file.

Simple calling a file by name, no parameters:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx

Some simple examples of different ways to call files:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-vbnet

Info and example of how to use ProcessStartInfo: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

These are just links I found when googling key terms ("vb.net open bat file no arguments", "vb.net process.Start", "vb.net ProcessStartInfo"... etc).